# Customise the "method is not supported for this route" error handling in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

```php
Route::post('order', 'OrderController@store')->name('order');
```

When I browse to the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/order` it shows the error:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Which is the correct.

But **I want to redirect user to home page** instead of showing this error.

Comment: Why would you even do that ? are you looking for a solution that handles only this `order` route, or you want to redirect for all the cases that throw this `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` error ?

Comment: I post a solution when you reply

Comment: Thank you @medilies . Ok , for now my solutions is:  created new route for redirect it to the home page: `Route::get('order', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');` but i don't know, is this better solution or not, but it works as i wanted

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that what you are trying to do seems like an anti-pattern for Laravel. **Accessing a route with the wrong method should be denied!**

I currently do not know about altering the default way of handling **the wrong method** error and I wouldn't advise to do that. But you can work around it:

## Patching

### Method 1

Keep your routes file clean but alter the original route line and add some lines to the beggining of the controller method

```php
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'order', [OrderController::class, 'store'])->name('order');
```

```php
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('get')) {
            return to_route('home');
        }
        // ...
```

### Method 2

Keep your controller clean, but add a line to your routes file

```php
Route::get('order', fn () => to_route('home'));
```